# Rebasing a commit from a branch to another branch

Tags: git

I have a question regarding git rebasing. There are tons of threads out there and I am not sure which one works with my usecase and I don't want to mess the remote branches since I am a beginner.

From what I've seen, I can use the commands:

- git branch to create or change the branch
- git rebase -i to rebase interactively
- git rebase <branch_name>
- git checkout to switch to the branch

Here is my case:

I have a branch branch_A that is on remote:
branch_A

Then, branch_A diverged to a branch branch_B and a branch branch_C (multiple commits)

branch_A - branch_B

branch_A - branch_C

Then, I did 3 commits (D1, D2 and D3) on branch B that I call branch branch_D:

branch_A - branch_B - D1 - D2 - D3 (branch_D)

branch_A - branch_C

I pushed these to remote so this state is on remote.

Now I want to move all the 3 commits from B - D to C - D to get:

branch_A - branch_B

branch_A - branch_C - D1 - D2 - D3 - branch_D

Note: The changes are minor (no conflicts can occur) so I could just make a patch and apply it but I want to improve my level at git.

What I fear is that I accidentally delete A, B, C or D (although I think deleting branch_D is a possibility but I know I can push force). I know I can use gitk --all without pushing to prevent things from getting bad.

I tried several things with git rebase  and git rebase -i but it didn't seem to work. Also I know I could git merge, but this is not what I want in this usecase.

Comment: So you explicitly want to use `git rebase` ?

Comment: @Paolo : I mean not necessarily but I have been told I can use rebase to do that.

Comment: Do you want to keep all 3 commits? You could use `git cherry-pick` which might be simpler

Comment: @Paolo Doesn't git cherry pick just pick the 3 commits to branch C? I think if I switch to git checkout C and then cherry pick D1 D2 and D3, I will have D1, D2 and D3 on the branch C, no?

Comment: All this is terribly unclear. Please name your commits and your branches with different conventions, or else this is just asking for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few key concepts:

- Commits point to their parents.
- Branches point to a single commit at a time. When we say something is "on a branch", we actually mean "reachable by following parents from that branch pointer".
- Commits are immutable. When we talk about "moving" or "amending" commits, we actually mean "creating new, similar, commits".
- Branches are independent - changing branch A has no immediate effect on branch B, or even on a branch called A on a server.

So, as I understand it, your commit graph looks like this:

```
      A        B       D
      |        v       v
      |  <-x <-x <-x <-x
      v /
... <-x  
        \
         <-x <-x
               ^
               C
```

What you want to create is this:

```
      A        B
      |        v
      |  <-x <-x
      v /
... <-x  
        \
         <-x <-x <-x <-x
               ^       ^
               C       D
```

Where the two new commits pointed at by D have been recreated with a parent of C rather than B. You don't need to touch branches A, B, and C; you just need to rebase branch D.

Until you're confident, you might want to create a backup of the current branch D, in case things go wrong:

```
git branch D_backup D
```

Then, the version of the `git rebase` command I find easiest to understand is "git rebase old_parent up_to_old_commit --onto new_parent", so:

```
git rebase B D --onto C
```

That should leave you with:

```
      A        B       D_backup
      |        v       v
      |  <-x <-x <-x <-x
      v /
... <-x  
        \
         <-x <-x <-x <-x
               ^       ^
               C       D
```

If it goes wrong, you can replace D with D_backup:

```
git branch -D D
git branch D D_backup
```

If it all looks fine, delete the backup, and overwrite the remote copy of branch D:

```
git branch -D D_backup
git push --force-with-lease origin D
```

Comment: Thanks, you got the graph of what I wanted right, I will try ASAP. Thank you for your fast and detailed answer :)

Comment: When I type git branch D D_backup, it tells me D_backup is an invalid object name, I tried D_b as a name and it didn't work. Is there an option needed? @IMSoP

Comment: @PackSciences The order of arguments is `git branch new_branch_name existing_branch_or_commit`, so `git branch D_backup D` creates "D_backup" based on the current state of "D".

Comment: Well I did the reverse order git branch D D_backup and it seemed to have worked as it shows on gitk.

Comment: After git rebase B D --onto C, it tells me: "fatal: Needed a single revision invalid B upstream" Yet B is clearly parent of D1. Do I need to be on a specific branch to do that? Currently I am in D.

Comment: Update: I needed to do origin/B instead of just B.

Comment: It seems to have worked fine, thank you very much.

Comment: @PackSciences Right, because "origin/B" refers to the _remote_ branch called "B" (or, your locally fetched copy of it), rather than a _local_ branch B. So everywhere in the diagrams above, "B" could be "origin/B". The only branch that _must_ be local for the command to work is "D", because you're checking it out and changing it locally.